# Getting the current url from the webbrowser

Tags: regex, vb.net

I've been trying to figure out how to get the current url to be used by the webbrowser in the following code:

```
Dim t As String = client.DownloadString("browserurl")
```

Here is my code so far:

```
    Dim client As New WebClient
    Dim t As String = client.DownloadString("browserurl")
    Dim p As String = ""
    Dim r As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(p)
    Dim v As String = reg.Match(t).Value
```

I'm trying to parse data from the websites which the webbrowser is visiting.

Comment: I understand that you want something like: 1st browser visits site1 which contains links to site2 & site3; 2nd parses the html information to extract the corresponding URLs. If this is what you want (not too clear, even after the corrections I made), note that this is a very wide problem and your code is very far away from accounting for it. Please, try to be more specific (and don't expect problems to be solved for you without doing any kind of effort) if you want to get help quickly.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! What I want actually is to get the current url from the webbrowser. Lets say i visit google. Then i want to get some info from the current url

Comment: I have already tried many different functions and strings to try do this. But everything has given me errors.

Comment: But if the browser visits google.com, it would mean that you had already input google.com on it. Why do you need regex? Is your problem that you don't know how to navigate to a given URL? Then ask so. You can use the  WebBrowser class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser(v=VS.110).aspx

Comment: I know how to get the current url from the navigated stage and put it on a label. But ubfortunately this is much harder to accomplish.

Comment: Please, think careful about what you want to accomplish, what you already know/have and how you expect to be helped. But don't start asking questions which do not make any sense. Why asking about regex at all?

Comment: I could have not mentioned regex but i thought it would be eazier to understand in what purpose it would be used. My apologies

Comment: Don't need to apologise, just understand how you should be doing things: mentioning random issues is not helpful to understand what you want. You have just to clearly transmit your problem. But bear in mind that there are some rules to ask in SO (take a look at the help section): you have to do some work by your own and ask specific questions. If you don't have too much knowledge about a given issue, the first step shouldn't be asking here but doing some learning/work by your own.

Comment: I suspect you want to extract/find/collect URLs from the page you navigated to. Otherwise, I do not see a point in a "regex" tag.

Comment: I guess thats True.  But i have hade this problem for a week and i have tried many different things to try Solveig this. I didnt think spamming my failed tried would help

Comment: @stribzhev  my real problem is how to get the current webbrowser url and use it for this function. Its not as easy as it looks.

Comment: I will make the last try: 1. this code isn't using WebBrowser (you can find a sample code about it in the link I posted in my comment above), but WebClient (you can use it to download a file, for example). 2. you have to provide url ("browserurl") to make any of these alternatives work; thus, you know already the url. 3. Regex is used to extract certain information (which follows regular patterns) in a given string; why you want to use it here at all? Anyone reading these 3 points will understand that your ideas are very unclear. Please think carefully and stop this not-useful conversation.

Comment: Hey,What your trying to get from a URL ?? comment a real time example

Comment: Hopefully this Will be detailed enough: I have a webbrowser setup using the webbrowser command. I have DIFFERENT links i navigate to and gather data from. THE ONLY PROBLEM I HAVE IS HOW TO GET WHAT URL I CURRENTLY VISIT USING THE WEBBROWSER AND USE IT FOR MY FUNCTION on this line:

Comment: Dim t As String = client.DownloadString("thecurrenturlofthewebbrowser")

Comment: What is "the webbrowser command"? If you're referring to the `WebBrowser` control that can be added via the ToolBox, you can use it's `Url` property: `Dim t As String = client.DownloadString(WebBrowser1.Url)`

Comment: Thanks Vincent! That was exactly what I was looking  for. When using the client.DownloadString do you know if its possible to get the current url like this, even if the page needs authorization? I am logged in on my webbrowser but it can not retrieve the source this way unfortunately.

Comment: I don't think you are able to use a `WebClient` for that. You could do some workarounds with the `HttpWebRequest` I believe, but the thing I'd recommend is to use the webbrowser control's [DocumentText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documenttext(v=vs.110).aspx) property: `Dim t As String = WebBrowser1.DocumentText`.

Comment: Thank you again for your very helpful answer Vincent! If there is any ting related to web design you need help with, just hit me up if u want :)